# Node references not visible

Tags: nodes

I have a nodetype with a nodereference field but my references are not visible on my page. I can't work with the nodereferencefield in views either.

Edit:
I created a contenttype 'Building' with a referencefield to the contenttype 'person'. When I create a 'Building' and I refer to a person, the person is not listed on the buildingpage. I haven't changed display settings.

Version: Drupal 7

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  More information is needed to help you.  What version of Drupal  are you using?  Have you created and saved content for the field and what value have you entered?  How has the view been defined?  If we cannot reproduce the problem or know the detailed steps you have done, then no-one will be able to tell what is going wrong.